# IP is shown in address bar when having a subdomain to a different IP

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain

Currently I have a domain name in a domain name provider. I set up as:

1. NS record: `example.com` points to `dns1.domainNameProvider.com`
2. A record: `sub1.example.com` points to `xx.xx.xx.xx`
3. A record: `sub2.example.com` points to `xx.xx.xx.xx`
4. A record: `*.example.com` points to `xx.xx.xx.xx`

Everything is good. Now, I want to put `sub2.example.com` to a different server `yy.yy.yy.yy`. I set up a new server with apache2 and updated point 3 to:

3. A record: `sub2.example.com` points to `yy.yy.yy.yy`

But now when I go to `sub2.example.com`, the address bar shows `yy.yy.yy.yy` instead of the sub domain name `sub2.example.com`. Is it possible to have subdomains running in different web servers? If yes, where did I do wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't ever happen as a result of DNS. Are you running some kind of redirection on the `yy.yy.yy.yy` server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your application or some component of your server is actually redirecting to the IP address.

In either chrome or firefox, pop open the debug/developer panel (ctrl + shift + k for firefox, ctrl + shift + j for chrome).  Click on the 'network' tab.  Make a request to the desired address (sub2.mydomain.com).
What I'm theorizing you'll see is a request to sub2.mydomain.com with a status of '302' or even '301'.  The next line will likely be yy.yy.yy.yy with a status of '200'

There's not really a way to get a DNS A record to behave in the way you described in a normal web browser, so it sounds like DNS is set right.  Is this a common CMS like wordpress, joomla, drupal, etc?  I think many of them need to have the domain (or subdomain) set in the application somewhere too.

Comment: Thanks Neil. By looking at the 'network' tab, it shows it was redirected and gave me a great hint in finding out the redirection occurred in the application level, so modifying the application configuration file fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!